# disabling copy constructor in c++ and use of an Object

Tags: c++

Using the following code :

```
#include <iostream>


class A
{
    public:
        A(int truc) : truc(truc) {}
        A(const A & other) = delete;
    private:
        int truc;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B(int machin, A a) : machin(machin), a(a) {}
    private:
        int machin;
        A a;
};

int main()
{
  A a(10);      
  B b(2,a);
  return 0;
}
```

I get a compile error "error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)"

How can I circonvent this problem if I still want the class A not to be able to be copied ?

Comment: `B` still has a default generated copy constructor.

Comment: Maybe store a reference to the original object so you don't need to copy it into B?

Comment: What exactly do you wish to happen? You've disabled copying and then tried to make a copy.

Comment: I'm just discovering the c++ world and the notions of value and references...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking `A` by value in `B::B(int machin, A a)` is the main issue, do `B::B(int machin, A& a)` or `B::B(int machin, const A& a)`.
The same applies to the assignment to the field within the constructor body. The field declaration in class `B` should hence be `A& a;` or `const A& a;`, respectively.

However, you probably also want to delete the assignment operator: `A& operator=( const A& ) = delete;`

Take a look at boost [non-copyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html).

Its implementation also depends on whether C++11 is available: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/core/noncopyable.hpp

Comment: I don't need the whole boost for having just a non-copyable class XD.

Comment: It still doesn't work and I still get an error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'

Comment: @user65490: completed the answer - an assignment to a field with a value type does also require that type to be copyable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

`B`'s constructor takes object of type `A` by value -> creates new object (copy)

```
B(...,A a) ...
       ^^^^ pass by value
```

Passing by reference won't create a new object (copy).

```
B(...,A &a)...
       ^^^^^ pass by reference -> no copy
```

Also, this means that you **can't** store it in `B` as object `A a`, because that would, again, create new object (copy), you'll have to store it as reference.

This could cause some problems:

```
B* createNewObject()
{
   A a(...); //local object is created
   B* ptr = new B(...,a); // reference in B now refers to local object
}// However, here is local object destroyed, so reference in B is now invalid (dangling reference)

int main()
{
   B *pb = createNewObject();
   //Any operation on B working with that invalid reference causes UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR
}
```

Additionaly, bear in mind that any change in `a` will also change object you passed (because that reference refers to same object you passed).

Answer (score 1):

Considering the alternative to copying is moving, you want:

```
   B(int machin, A&& a) : machin(machin), a(a) {}
```

That correctly disallows `A a(10); B b(2,a);` which *is* a copy of `a`. You'd now need `std::move(a)` there.

Comment: `B::B(int machin, A&& a) : a(std::move(a));` It should be moved again right ? Otherwise, it tries to call copy constructor.